How to implement a solid box-shadow effect in React Native?
Has anyone one else attempted to achieve this effect in React Native?:

A component with a solid shadow effect to give an illusion of depth.
As you may know React-Native does not support CSS box-shadow. It does have a very close equivalent though, the shadowOffset property, which only works on iOS (What was used for the above example). And from what I gather Android's elevation property does not have a setting for blur radius to have it be solid.
I have tried the react-native-shadow and the react-native-shadow-2 packages. Both seem to have problems shadowing the actual component, it instead does it to the margins and doesn't seem to handle borderRadius either. Maybe missed something.
The closest cross-platform solution I could get was to add a thicker bottom borderWidth. But as you can see the appearance is still a bit off:

If you have a solution for this design problem on Android, please lmk. There is no way there isn't a simple way to get such a simple effect, right?

No need to add shadow to your buttons to have the same effect. If you look closely, the effect has just extra bottom width from the bottom as compared to any other side.
The magic is in borderBottomWidth prop, just keep the value of this prop must be greater than the borderWidth of the container in order to get the effect.
Here, I have tried creating same effect and it looks like this:

Your container style should look something like this.
imageContainer: {
    width: '50%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 10, // Add more bottom width than regular to achieve the effect
}

Here's the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/6KvkXqcYv_j1WnWAwEFPG
